# No such Element Exception using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
chrome_path=r"C:\Users\Priyanshu\Downloads\Compressed\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/?")
search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys("laptop")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(""" //*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/section/ul/li[2]""").click()
```

I am getting no such  element present in the last line of code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
chrome_path=r"C:\Users\Priyanshu\Downloads\Compressed\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=laptop&otracker=start&as-show=off&as=off")

driver.find_element_by_xpath(""" //*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/section/ul/li[2]""").click()
```

If I am doing like this its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is not immediately available, [wait for it to be present first](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

search = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'q')))
search.send_keys("laptop")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/section/ul/li[2]'))
element.click()
```

Note that, assuming you want to get to the "Popularity" menu header, why don't simplify the XPath expression and use the element's text:

```
//li[. = "Popularity"]
```